# Unable to rename Ceph storage cluster

Tags: ceph

We are Unable to rename the ceph storage cluster name. Whenever we set up a ceph cluster, it by default get "ceph" as a cluster name.

We have tried one command which presents in official documentation https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E52668_01/E66514/html/ceph-cluster-install-config.html

The command error that we got is mentioned in below link.

[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k9mw7.png)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your version of ceph-deploy does not support that option.

In any case, I wouldn't recommend to change the default name as it could cause some known issues. The ceph team even said that they would remove this functionality.

(FYI http://lists.ceph.com/pipermail/ceph-users-ceph.com/2017-June/018497.html)

Answer (score 0):

Non-default names were intended to faciliate the running of multiple clusters on the same hardware.  Turns out almost nobody ever actually did that, and full support in ceph-deploy lagged and then was eventually removed.  While existing clusters will run at least as of Nautilus, managing them is becoming increasingly difficult.  Upstream has deprecated the practice and it will eventually be removed entirely from code, so a custom name today would be folly at best.

The name is really only ever used internally by the cluster; there isn't much or anything to be gained by changing it.  If your motivation is for some reason to have multiple clusters' conf files in the same directory, eg. for rbd-mirror, remember that the conf filename is in many regards arbitrary, you can rename the file on a client at will.